# Rails: Search & Filter Books by Category with Info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I need some help please. I am building a digital library, and I would like to search for books by name, author and description, and also filter them by categories in which each book is categorized.

Each book is placed under a sub-category which is placed under a category. So for each book, it belongs to a category which belongs to a sub-category.

The model association is like this;

**This is the code for the category model**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sub_categories
  has_many :books
end
```

**This is the code for the sub-category model**

```
class SubCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
  belongs_to :category
 end
```

**This is the code for the book model**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories
  has_many :subcategories

  def self.search(keywords)
    if keywords
      where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR author LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%").order('id DESC')
    else
      order('id DESC') 
    end
  end
 end
```

**Books controller code**

```
def index 
  if params['category'].blank? or params['category']['id'].blank? 
    @books = Book.all 
  else 
    category = Category.find(params['category']['id']) 
    @books = category.books 
  end 
  @books = @books.search(params[:keywords]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order('created_at DESC') 
end
```

I have an issue that I would like to fix, I have a quick search form and an advanced search form. The Advanced search form is working, but I would like only display the advanced search form on the Books Index page only when a search action is initiated, else it should not display.

Also, when a search is conducted using the Advanced Search Form, it should show me this message "**Showing Books for :Keywords**" when results are found, and if no result is found it should show me this message "**No results found**"

**Here is my Advanced Search Form code in the Books index page**

```
<%= form_tag(books_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords] %>
    <%= collection_select :category, :id, Category.all.order('name ASC'), :id, :name,{include_blank: 'Select Category'} %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

How do I implement an if statement for this advanced search.

How do I use an if statement to display the advanced search form on the Books Index page only when a search action is initiated, and also, when a search is conducted with the Advanced Search Form, it should show me this message "**Showing Books for :Keywords**" when results are found, and if no result is found it should show me this message "**No results found**"

I have tried implementing the No records found on the books index page from the suggestion of a contributor here, but I also get an error.

**Here is my code**

```
<%= render 'advanced_search' if @show_advanced_search %>
<% if @books.empty? %>
  <p>No Records Found</p>

<% else %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

[image: Error Message]

**Please I will appreciate any form of help. Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You can set a a flag when a quick search has been made:

```rb
def index 
  if params['category'].blank? or params['category']['id'].blank? 
    @books = Book.all 
  else 
    category = Category.find(params['category']['id']) 
    @books = category.books 
    @show_advanced_search = true
  end 
  @books = @books.search(params[:keywords]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order('created_at DESC') 
end
```

Then, in the view:

```rb
<%= render 'advanced_search' if @show_advanced_search %>
```

UPDATE: Conditional text based on results:

```
<% if @books %>
  <h3>Showing books for <%= @keywords %></h3>
  .
  .
  .
<% else %>
  No results found.
<% end %>
```

Comment: No it is not, I just used it to try to see if it will work, I don't know how to implement the if statement for the Advanced Search From, maybe I should remove it from the question so that it doesn't confuse anyone.

Comment: I will try it out asap and then let you know if it works. 

Can you also help with the search results message, it should show me this message ** "Showing Books for :Keywords"** when results are found, and if no result is found it should show me this message **"No results found"**.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: So sorry that I am asking so many questions, please where do I include the conditional text based on results? In the book model search or the Book index page. I jut need more clarification please.

Comment: In the view. It can be inferred by the ERB indicators (`<%= %>`)

Comment: I am so sorry for the delay, I made the **advanced search form as a partial**, and then rendered it using  `<%= render 'advanced_search' if @show_advanced_search %>`, however the advanced search no longer shows up when I try to search. If I use `<%= render 'advanced_search' if @books %>`, it shows the **advanced search form**, but I only want it to display when I make a search

Comment: I am also having an issue with the `<% if @books %>
  <h3>Showing books for <%= @keywords %></h3>` implementation. I have added a screenshot of the error.